# Convert time from Apache Log to Epoch time

Tags: java, sql, epoch, grok

Edit: Working solution. Original question below.

```
private Timestamp extractTimestamp(Object timestamp) {
    try {
        return Timestamp.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(timestamp))));
    } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("Not in Epoch format");
    }
    try {
        return Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(String.valueOf(timestamp)));
    } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Not in UTC format");
    }
    try {
        return Timestamp.valueOf(String.valueOf(timestamp));
    } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        System.out.println("Not in SQL format");
    }
    try {               
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss Z");
        Date date = formatter.parse(String.valueOf(timestamp));
        return Timestamp.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(date.getTime()));
    } catch(ParseException e) {
        System.out.println("Not in Apache Log format");
    }
    // Return current time if none found
    return Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
}
```

---

I am attempting to parse the timestamp from an Apache access log and turn it into an Epoch timestamp or an SQL timestamp. I already have code in place to convert from epoch to the SQL timestamp for other formats so my main concern is to get to Epoch format or any other easily convertable format. I am currently using a Grok pattern for it however I am looking for a more efficient way of extracting the time.

Below is a sample of the log and timestamp I am pulling and my current code:

*127.0.0.1 127.0.0.1 - - [04/Nov/2016:08:00:02 -0400] "GET /loc/ation" 200 163 "-" "-" 26 163 37526*

*04/Nov/2016:08:00:02 -0400*

```
private Timestamp extractTimestamp(Object timestamp) {
  try {
    return Timestamp.from(Instant.ofEpochMilli(Long.valueOf(String.valueOf(timestamp))));
  } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println("Not in Epoch format");
  }
  try {
    return Timestamp.from(Instant.parse(String.valueOf(timestamp)));
  } catch(DateTimeParseException e) {
    System.out.println("Not in UTC format");
  }
  try {
    return Timestamp.valueOf(String.valueOf(timestamp));
  } catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
    System.out.println("Not in SQL Time format");
  }
  try {
    // Sample timestamp: 04/Nov/2016:08:00:02 -0400
    String apacheLogExpression = "%{NUMBER:day}/%{WORD:month}/%{NUMBER:year}:%{NUMBER:hour}:%{NUMBER:minute}:%{NUMBER:second}\\s%{GREEDYDATA:offset}";
    Grok compiledPattern = dictionary.compileExpression(apacheLogExpression);
    Map<String, String> values = compiledPattern.extractNamedGroups(String.valueOf(timestamp));
    System.out.println(values);
  } catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("Not in Apache Log format");
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  // Return current time if none found
  return Timestamp.from(Instant.now());
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    String logTime = "04/Nov/2016:08:00:02 -0400";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy:hh:mm:ss Z");
    Date date = formatter.parse(logTime);
    System.out.println(date);
```

Will print `Fri Nov 04 14:00:02 EET 2016` and basically get `java.util.Date` object

Comment: This worked perfectly, thanks! I've edited my post with the updated code in case anyone in the future stumbles across it in the future.

Comment: I think there's a potential bug in this: the 'hh' code in the SimpleDateFormat should have been capitalized 'HH' so that it's hours in 24-hour time (13 = 1pm) instead of am/pm.